# SQL pagination performance issue

Tags: sql-server, pagination, sqlperformance

In our project we have some large data tables (100M), the data representation in UI would be joining three more tables along with this table and inside of SQL SP we are using Offset & fetch for pagination.
UI filter can be from any of these 4 SQL tables. This pagination is causing very bad performance issue.
What is the better way to handle it.

WE are using latest version of Azure SQL Managed instance, how to improve pagination in SQL with better performance in UI.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: **We can't help you unless you post your actual query**. While we _can_ give general guidance for how to implement pagination, you've hinted at custom logic going on, which means a generalisation won't be of much use.

Comment: Also, better yet: **please** post a reproduction to SqlFiddle or DBFiddle.

Comment: "better performance in UI." - that's not a SQL question. UI performance is completely unrelated to query performance. Hire someone who knows the UI platforms and frameworks you're using and can optimize it.

Comment: This is related to SQL pagination only.. Since data is large when pagination goes to last page, fetch row takes time.

Comment: You should look into [Keyset Pagination](https://taylorbrazelton.com/posts/2019/03/offset-vs-seek-pagination/) it's much more performant than Rowset Pagination